# i got this error message - "glusterd : unrecognized service"

Tags: 14.04

I was trying to implement `glusterfs` on my pc(ubuntu 14.04).I did the following steps:-

1) Install python-software-properties.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

2)Add the GlusterFS PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gluster/glusterfs-3.5
sudo apt-get update
```

3) Install glusterfs-server.

```
sudo apt-get install glusterfs-server
```

now i am not able to run glusterd service on ubuntu 14.04.

```
Error : 
glusterd : unrecognized service
```

and we have no file named "glusterd" in /etc/init.d

so can you please help us to resolve this issue.
Thank you in advance

Comment: what is the output of `glusterfs --version`

Comment: glusterfs 3.5.3 built on Nov 18 2014 03:53:22
Repository revision: git://git.gluster.com/glusterfs.git
Copyright (c) 2006-2013 Red Hat, Inc. <http://www.redhat.com/>
GlusterFS comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
It is licensed to you under your choice of the GNU Lesser
General Public License, version 3 or any later version (LGPLv3
or later), or the GNU General Public License, version 2 (GPLv2),
in all cases as published by the Free Software Foundation.

Comment: Then you have it laready installed in your system. Now how do you start the service? what command do you use?

Comment: i used "sudo service glusterd start" and "/etc/init.d/glusterd start" but none is working

Comment: try this `sudo service glusterfs-server start`

Comment: this command is giving output:- "start: job is already running :glusterfs-server"

Comment: I make an answer please check it

Comment: @why you removed the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably run other service, the service is named `glusterfs-server`

so the correct command to run is:

```
sudo service glusterfs-server start
```

If the output is

```
start: job is already running :glusterfs-server
```

This means the service is already running

you can restart it using the command

```
sudo service glusterfs-server restart
```

or to stop the service

```
sudo service glusterfs-server stop
```

---

The glusterfs service is just the  `glusterfs-server` in Ubuntu, the glusterfsd is not a service you can run it using the command `sudo glusterfsd   glusterfsd [options] [mountpoint]` check `man glusterfsd` for more information.

Please read [this](http://ludwigkb.blogspot.com/2012/06/glusterfs-on-ubuntu-server-1204-lts.html) AND [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-redundant-storage-pool-using-glusterfs-on-ubuntu-servers) for more information about glusterfs with Ubuntu

Comment: glusterfs-server is already running but i want to start gluster daemon.                i want to start "glusterd service" .

Comment: what is the output of `sudo glusterfsd`

Comment: [2015-06-02 06:09:01.857885] C [glusterfsd.c:1445:parse_cmdline] 0-glusterfs: ERROR: parsing the volfile failed (No such file or directory)

USAGE: glusterfsd [options] [mountpoint]

Comment: ok now check my updated answer and please note that Ubuntu has its own  of dealing with things so tutorials for Debian or RedHat may not be applicable to Ubuntu so Please read the links provided above.

Comment: i have already read those links.Actually, " glusterd " is a service that get started with "glusterfs-server" automatically but in my pc there is no file in /etc/init.d named "glusterd"

Comment: Also in mine I installed it here also samething, i serached a little, this is the how ubuntu use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24370/discussion-between-ashish-aggarwal-and-maythux).

Answer (score 0):

sudo service glusterfs-service restart -- gives glusterfs-server running process 
when tried sudo gluster peer probe server2.example.com 
Success : Probe on localhost not needed

actually, server2.example.com is an entry in /etc/hosts in the following manner -

ipaddr server1.example.com gluster1
ipaddr ....